# Problema Con Zona Horaria en sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Los Servidores de sql se encuentran en otro país y cuando consulto la hora  GETDATE() y lo inserto en un tabla de me da un hora distinta a la de mi país hay alguna forma a la base de datos establecerlo como zona horaria de un país especifico.

Comment: como dice @crrlos revisa esta documentación (https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/queries/at-time-zone-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 1):

Usa la instruccción `inputdate AT TIME ZONE timezone`, ejemplo:

```
GETDATE() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' --reemplaza UTC por  tu zona horaria
```